# How can to decrease the total amount in cash distribution with changing the total amount donation

Tags: php, mysql

I have two PHP file with the same query to display the total amount of donation.

**List for total donations:**
[image: Total donation amount]

---

**List for cash distribution:**
[image: Cash distribution]

**My main problem is, how can I decrease the total amount in cash distribution when I distribute cash without changing the total amount because those two have the same query.**

Comment: Is it true that you are talking about --- somebodies donate money, and then you distribute the money received to other beneficiaries  ?

Comment: @KenLee yes it is true.

Comment: If you need someone to do your development for you, please hire a developer.  If you intend to do the development yourself, show us your best failed coding attempt and isolate where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same query for the "amount of donation" in both the donation page and distribution page, that's fine because both pages show the "amount of donation" which reflects the true picture.

However, you should build another query to show the "amount of distribution".

For example, if the donation table is "donation" and distribution table is "distribution" and the amount field is "amount".

Then for the total donation, the query will be something like

**select sum(amount) as totaldonation from donation**

So the query may be like:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","dbuser","xxxpassword","maindb");

$qresult = $conn -> query("select sum(amount) as totaldonation from donation" );

$qrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresult); 
$totaldonation=$qrow["totaldonation"];
```

And for the total distribution, the query will be something like

**select sum(amount) as totaldistribution from distribution**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","dbuser","xxxpassword","maindb");

$qresult = $conn -> query("select sum(amount) as totaldistribution from distribution" );

$qrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qresult); 
$totaldistribution=$qrow["totaldistribution"];
```

Now you can display the two figures on both the pages, and just to display one more data as the "balance left" which is $totaldonation - $totaldistribution

Comment: Please demand that the OP try something before you consider posting an answer.  This way askers will learn that abusing volunteers is not welcome.

Comment: @KenLee thanks, I didn't think it that way, what I think is everytime I add a money in donation it should also add in distribution db table, but that will take too many data everytime I add donation.